# VB Avoiding text box that is occupied

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am making an application where there is a form with a column of text boxes that are filled from two different forms with a button on each. when the button of these forms are clicked they input the results into the text boxes in the column.

the problem I am having is that say i click (form2.button 1) three times it will occupy text boxes 1,2 and 3. Now say I want to use (form1.button 1) to input data into text box 4 it will occupy text box 1.

I have each button set up for multiple clicks so I would like to understand how i can have is so say(form2.button 1) is clicked then (form1.button1) will go to 2nd click for example. there are 10 text boxes so I will need it so that they react to how many times each has been clicked.

Comment: Why can't you check if a textbox is filled before trying to fill it?

Comment: ive tried with if val(textbox1.text) = < 0 or val(textbox1.text) = 0> and it still overlaps if the button clicks are at different stages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the TextBoxes were called TextBox1 thru TextBox10, you could use a sub like this:

```
Public Sub AddValue(ByVal value As String)
    For i As Integer = 1 To 10
        Dim tbName As String = "TextBox" & i
        Dim matches() As Control = Me.Controls.Find(tbName, True)
        If matches.Length > 0 AndAlso TypeOf matches(0) Is TextBox Then
            Dim tb As TextBox = DirectCast(matches(0), TextBox)
            If tb.Text.Trim.Length = 0 Then
                tb.Text = value
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    Next
    MessageBox.Show("All TextBoxes are already taken!")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just store a counter variable in the form that contains the textboxes, say `NextTextBoxNumber` that increments each time a textbox is filled in and then you know exactly which textbox to go to next based upon the value of this variable?

Also, to continue with @Oded's comment, you can easily accomplish what he meant using something along the lines of `If Textbox1.Text <> "" Then ...`

Does that make sense??

Comment: Hi there, thanks for response, I understand the if.textbox1.text <> bit but could you expand a bit on the nexttextbox number a bit. many thanks.